# Captured value within completion handler not mutating

Tags: swift, asynchronous

So I have here an `async` method defined on an `actor` type. The issue im having is that `people` isnt being mutated at all; mainly due to what from what I understand concurrency issues. From what I think I know the completion handler is executed concurrently on the same thread and so cannot mutate `people`.

Nonetheless my knowledge in this area is pretty foggy, so any suggestions to solve it and maybe a better explanation as to why this is happening would be great! Ive thought of a few things but im still new to concurrency.

```
func getAllPeople() async -> [PersonModelProtocol] { 
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        var people: [Person] = []
        
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request!) { data, response, error in
            do {
                let newPeople = try! decoder.decode([Person].self, from: data!)
                people = newPeople
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        return people
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **do** want to use `async/await` you have to use the appropriate API.

```
func getAllPeople() async throws -> [Person] { 
    let (data, _ ) = try await session.data(for: request!)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: data)
}
```

In a synchronous context you cannot `return` data from a completion handler anyway.

Answer (score 1):

vadian is right but it's better-expressed as a computed property nowadays.

```swift
var allPeople: [PersonModelProtocol] {
  get async throws {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(
      [Person].self,
      from: await session.data(for: request!).0
    )
  }
}
```

And also, your code does mutate `people`, but returning its empty value before it gets mutated.